# Using postman to test firebase returns 401 unauthorised with right api key

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am using postman to test my application that i added to firebase add project. I am trying to trigger a cloud notification from a postman to test purposes but its returning 401 unauthorised always. I double checked the api key and instance key even from google settings> project settings nad its correctly entered. Please help me find the problem. Sharing the screenshot of postman below
[image: api key]

[image: Postman header]

[image: Postman body]

Comment: Use the Server Key found at your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) _Project Settings > Cloud Messaging_

Comment: Thanks Bob, just used the legacy server key and it worked. should have kept eyes open for it. I was just using the web api key in general tab